# Is a subset of a recursively enumerable set also recursively enumerable?

Tags: logic, computability

Given a r.e set A, is any subset of A: A', also r.e.? Why?

I'm pretty sure the answer is yes, but I can't find any viable proof around the internet.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$\mathbb{N}$ is recursively enumerable. Is every subset of $\mathbb{N}$ recursively enumerable?

Comment: Why didn't I think of that